# How do i setup live id integration with sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to configure sharepoint 2010 to allow live id user to be logged in.
Does it have to be https?
And how do I allow all live id users?

Comment: There is some information on this for MOSS 2007/WSS3. checkout http://spwla.codeplex.com/ I've been trying to get it to work with SP 2010, however - no success so far.